# Initializing HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, spring

I want to initialize **HttpServletResponse** Class,
Below is my current code, which is keep returning null point exception  :(
**How Can I initialize HttpServletResponse Class?** I have to use this instance to create another class , I should send this instance as constructor param
Should I implement all interface methods of HttpServletResponse?

```
    
import com.bside11th.bside.config.Constant;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
public class AccountController {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    GoogleOauth googleOauth = new GoogleOauth(objectMapper);

    ServletWebRequest servletContainer = (ServletWebRequest) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletResponse response = servletContainer.getResponse();
    OAuthService oAuthService = new OAuthService(googleOauth, response);


    /**
     * 유저 소셜 로그인으로 리다이렉트 해주는 url
     * [GET] /accounts/auth
     * @return void
     */
    @GetMapping("/auth/{socialLoginType}") //GOOGLE이 들어올 것이다.
    public void socialLoginRedirect(@PathVariable(name="socialLoginType") String SocialLoginPath) throws IOException {
        Constant.SocialLoginType socialLoginType= Constant.SocialLoginType.valueOf(SocialLoginPath.toUpperCase());
        oAuthService.request(socialLoginType);
    }
}
```